# Only Icons Missing from desktop

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, desktop-icons

I opened the PC in the morning, and this is what I got:
[image: Desktop]
[image: This PC]
[image: Start Menu]
[image: Control Panel-A]
[image: Control Panel-B]
As is visible the icons of the UWA apps were no affected and the start menu also is unaffected.

When Control Panel is in category view the entire page is empty and in large/small icons the name is visible, no icons.

I deleted the `iconcache.db` in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local` folder. Following the instructions here: [How to fix missing icons in the taskbar and start menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/462632/how-to-fix-missing-icons-in-the-taskbar-and-start-menu). But to no avail and now windows is not rebuilding the cache.

I also ran `sfc /scannow` but no changes took place.

What should I do?

---

**(01/01/2016 8:00PM GMT +5:30) Edit:** I tried opening the system properties and I got `0x8000ffff` error and this:

[image: <code>0x8000ffff</code> error]

Then I closed the popup and pressed the OK button on the `System Properties` Windows and I got `0x8007057A` error:

[image: <code>0x8007057A</code> error]

Opening the Image Backup Control Panel page I again got an `0x8007000E` error:

[image: Control Panel <code>0x8007000E</code> Error]

I tried using system restore via advanced startup but once again I got `0x800FFFF` error.

**P.S.:** I did try restarting, didn't work.

Comment: I know this is going to sound like a dumb question, but have you tried Restarting the computer? (not a "shutdown" and power on, but actually using the "restart" function)

Comment: Have you tried a [System Restore](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4588-system-restore-windows-10-a.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I researched on the `0x8007057A` error and [found](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0777e4de-157a-4e8d-85ac-34e6741e7c3a/catastrophic-failure-0x8000fff-in-property-page-when-checking-system-protection-in-system?forum=w7itprogeneral) that it is caused by [corrupted user profile](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/fix-a-corrupted-user-profile) so I decide to follow the tseps. But before I did that I updated to Windows 10 Threshold 2 (v1511, Build 10586) and upgrade to it fixed the problem.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, could you tell me exactly what you did, creating a new user account doesn't seem to work for me