# All icons missing

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, icons

As the title says, all of my icons are suddenly missing (Windows Explorer, Registry, Task Manager). Only metro icons in the start menu are showing

This is my current situation:
[image: No icons]
Additionally, I can't open any file or folder properties

Things I've tried:

- restarted windows
- deleted icon cache
- scanned with sfc /scannow
- scanned with Malwarebytes
- repaired SageThumbs
- disabled Stardock Fences

Even in safe mode the problem still occurs. Also tested with another freshly created local user - still the same

Comment: At this point, your solution solution, is to try and Reset your installation.

Comment: Could you check with another user account? See [similar Q/A](http://superuser.com/questions/1020219/only-icons-missing-from-desktop) where it was caused by corrupted user profile.

Comment: @miroxlav I have already tried that (see last sentence), didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I finally had to do an "in-place upgrade" of Windows 10. 20 minutes later everything is back to normal, programs and settings weren't touched. The icons are back again, yay!